# Access on elements which will be loaded with ajax after DOM is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to modify the webpage with a safari extension. 
I inserted jquery as a StartScript and my own script as a End-Script.
My End-Script looks like:

```
    $(function() {
        console.log(getElementById('id-of-the-element'));
        console.log($('#id-of-the-element'));
        console.log(document);
    });
```

And the output looks like this: 
[console.log - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBT4V.png)

First log is completly null, 
the second is a empty jQuery-Object but the third is the complete html-document, even the by id selected elements are inside of the document.

Inside of the document there isn't the element, I need, because they gonna be loaded with ajax after the DOM is complete I think.
Is there any way to wait until all ajax calls of a page is done?
Like a function which waits for the DOM and! the whole ajax-stuff?

@Jayant Varshney: thx for the hint

Answer (score 0):

It should be, making sure your id exists in the html.

```
$(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('id-of-the-element'));
    console.log($('#id-of-the-element').html()) //if you want to see the content ;
    console.log(document); //this prints the document which is correct.
});
```